# How to read and display unstructured Excel sheet data in Angular6

Tags: angular6

Is there any way to Read unstructured data from an excel sheet and display it out in the browser as table using Angular6 .

Currently i am looking at `wijmo.grid.xlsx Module` which does both, but it is not free.

```
importExcelAsync() {
    var fileInput = <HTMLInputElement>$('#importFile')[0];
    if (fileInput.files[0]) {
        wijmo.grid.xlsx.FlexGridXlsxConverter.loadAsync(this.flexGrid, fileInput.files[0], { includeColumnHeaders: this.includeColumnHeader });
    }
}
```

Is there any free alternative for this, / or any other way to read and display data from `xlsx` in Angular6. Please Help.